# Is the Google branded Galaxy Nexus HSPA+ the same as GT-I9250?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

I purchased the Galaxy Nexus HSPA+ directly from Google Play. I'm looking to buy a Proclip holder that's specific to the Samsung Galaxy Nexus (GT-I9250) http://www.proclipusa.com/brodit-device-holder/samsung-galaxy-nexus-(gt-i9250)/holder-with-tilt-swivel-511324-18854.aspx

Is the Google sold device the same form factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the HSPA+ Galaxy Nexus phone from Google Play Store is the i9250 model.  That clip should fit it just fine.